# Convert .p8 to .p12 ceriticate for iOS Push Notification

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I am working on iOS project and needed to setup a third party notification.
It's required on the third party to upload a .p12 file for pushing notification but I only have a .p8 file.
Is there anyway to convert it to .p12?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a convert .p8 to the .p12.
[You can create .p12](https://calvium.com/how-to-make-a-p12-file/) from scratch.

Comment: HI @schornon. Thanks for sharing the link!